# JDBC call procedure , occur non supported SQL92

Tags: oracle, jdbc, procedure

```
    callStmt= conn.prepareCall("{call get_id(?,?,?);}");
    callStmt.setString(1,"T_CUSTOMER");
    callStmt.registerOutParameter(2,Types.VARCHAR);
    callStmt.setString(3,"GD");
    callStmt.execute();
    String string = callStmt.getString(2);
    System.out.println(string);
```

I search in google and found this error occurs may because of "{}", But how can I call a oracle procedure without "{}" ? or which token should I use ?

Comment: Try removing the `;` inside the call escape (so use `{call get_id(?,?,?)}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The braces won't work for Oracle. Take them out and you should be good to go. Oracle traditionally uses placeholders that being with the character ':' followed by a word.

If you don't like the call keyword, you can use this:
    "BEGIN get_id(?,?,?); END;"

Comment: A JDBC driver is required to support the `{call ..}` JDBC escape, I would be  surprised i it wouldn't be supported by the Oracle driver. I'd sooner think the cause is the `;` inside the call escape.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel If the ';' is the cause, then I would vote down the question as it would imply a lack of research.